# Obtaining bounds on moments of subexponentially decaying functional.

Tags: real-analysis, probability

Let $p:\mathbb R^d\to [0,\infty)$ satisfy the bound $p(x)\leq\exp(-\|x\|^{4/3})$, where $(\mathbb R^d, \|\cdot\|)$ is a Hilbert space (note: I haven't assumed that $p$ integrates to $1$). I'd like to obtain bounds of the form $$\left|\int_{\mathbb R^d}x_1^n\,p(x)\mathrm \,dx\right|\leq C(n)\left(\frac{3n}{4}\right)!\qquad\qquad (\star)$$ with $C(n)$ possibly growing exponentially in $n$ (and ideally independent of the dimension, $d$) and where I've used the Gamma function to define the factorial.

---

**Some comments about why I think the bound may hold**. Firstly, note that $$\exp(-\|x\|^2)\leq p(x)\leq \exp(-\|x\|),$$ at least for large $\|x\|$, and the moments of $\exp(-\|x\|^2)$ grow like $n!!\simeq(n/2)!$ (possibly up to an exponential factor, which I don't mind). And, moments of $\exp(-\|x\|)$ grow like $n!$, so I hope that moments of $p(x)$ lie somewhere in between.

Secondly, if $d=1$, 
\begin{align}M_n:&=\int_\mathbb R|x|^n\exp(-|x|^{4/3})dx\\
&=\int_\mathbb R-\frac{4}{3}|x|^{n-1/3}\frac{d}{dx}\exp(-|x|^{4/3})dx\\
&\stackrel{\mathrm{IBP}}{=}\int_\mathbb R\frac{4}{3}(n-\frac{1}{3})|x|^{n-4/3}\exp(-|x|^{4/3})dx = \frac{4}{3}(n-\frac{1}{3})M_{n-\frac{4}{3}},
\end{align}
this suggests we can inductively/recursively obtain a bound of the form $|M_n|\leq C\cdot\left(\frac{3n}{4}\right)!$.

I would greatly appreciate any help making the above precise and completing the argument for arbitrary $d\in\mathbb N$ (if the bound holds at all!).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $I$ be your integral.  One kind of bound is to observe that $|x_1|\le \|x\|$, resulting in $$I\le \int_{\mathbb R^d} \|x\|^n p(x)\,dx = \frac{2\pi^{d/2}}{\Gamma(d/2)} \int_0^\infty r^{n+d-1} \exp( -r^{4/3}) \,dr.$$  On substituting $t=r^{4/3}$ we get 
$$I\le\frac{3\pi^{d/2}}{2\Gamma(d/2)}\int_0^\infty t^{3(n+d)/4 - 1} e^{-t} \,dt = \frac{3\pi^{d/2}\Gamma(3(d+n)/4)}{2\Gamma(d/2)}.$$

Is this good enough for you?

Comment: Slightly more elaborate versions of this calculation will give exact formulas for integrals such as $\int_{\mathbb R^d} x_1^n \exp(-\|x\|^{-4/3})\,dx$, $\int_{\mathbb R^d} |x_1|^n \exp(-\|x\|^{-4/3})\,dx$ and $\int_{\mathbb R^d:x_1>0} x_1^n \exp(-\|x\|^{-4/3})\,dx$.